# How to import Data from a python pandas DataFrame to Airtable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rest, airtable

How can I import data from a Pandas DataFrame to airtable.
I've been searching for hours now, havent seen anything.
For example this is my dataframe :

```
ar = numpy.array([[1.1, 2, 3.3, 4], [2.7, 10, 5.4, 7], [5.3, 9, 1.5, 15]])
df = pandas.DataFrame(ar,columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

And it gives this :

```
   A   B    C   D
 1.1   2  3.3   4
 2.7  10  5.4   7
 5.3   9  1.5  15
```

So how do I import this DataFrame into a table named "alpha" and DB named "test" in **Airtable** ?
To have this data in my table.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, i figured something out.It worked perfectly
So i have this table presented like this :

```
id name  surname age
1  Ekane Emile   21
2  Ekane Emile   21
```

I wrote the following code :

```
import pandas
import requests

#AUTHENTICATION
#Global variables
AIRTABLE_BASE_ID = 'BASE_ID'
AIRTABLE_API_KEY= 'API_KEY'
AIRTABLE_TABLE_NAME='TABLE_NAME'

endpoint = f'https://api.airtable.com/v0/{AIRTABLE_BASE_ID}/{AIRTABLE_TABLE_NAME}'

#Headers
headers= {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {AIRTABLE_API_KEY}",
    "Content-Type":"application/json"
    }
#Dataframe to json data conversion 
df = {
      "fields": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Ekane",
        "surname": "Emile",
        "age": "21",
      }
}

df_to_json = df.to_json()
data =  json.dumps(df_to_json)

#post request 
r = requests.post(endpoint, data=data, headers=headers)
print(r.json())
print(r.status_code) #200 if it works
```

And it worked, hope it helps.
Note : The *"fields"* object must be present